# Enabling touchpad tapping after installing dwm on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, touchpad

I installed Arch Linux and [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org) window manager. But the tapping of touchpad doesn't work.

I know how to enable the tapping; I find the id of my touchpad, using this command:

```
~ xinput --list
Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
  ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I can see that the id is 10. Then I can list its properties:

```
~ xinput --list-props 10
Device 'Elan Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (172):   1
    libinput Tapping Enabled (307): 0
```

Here I can see that property of `tapping` with the id of 307 is not set to 1, so it's not enabled, I can enable it with this command:

```
xinput --set-prop 10 307 1
```

And it works. Now I wanted to write a script to automate this process, so I don't have to do it everytime I reboot. I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

touchpad_id=$(xinput --list | awk '/Touchpad/ {print $5}' | tr -d 'id=')
tapping_id=$(xinput --list-props $touchpad_id | awk '/libinput Tapping Enabled \(/ {print $4}' | tr -d '():')

# Enable Tapping
xinput --set-prop $touchpad_id $tapping_id 1
```

And this script works when I run it in the terminal (using `./touchpad_click.sh`).

Next, I modified the dwm source code to run a script everytime it starts. I added the below function between the `run(void)` and `scan(void)` functions of `dwm.c`:

```
void
runAutostart(void) {
        system("~/.dwm/autostart.sh &");
}
```

Added its header:

```
static void runAutostart(void);
```

And called the function in `main()`, right before calling `run()`:

```
scan();
runAutostart();
run();
```

And then compiled the `dwm.c` file with `sudo make install`. Compiled successfully.

And then wrote this script, `autostart.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Enable Tapping for Touchpad
./touchpad_click.sh
```

And put both `autostart.sh` and `touchpad_click.sh` in the `~/.dwm` directory. I also made sure to give both files `execute` permission:

```
chmod +x autostart.sh touchpad_click.sh
```

And I verify that by:

```
~ ls -lhA
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amir amir  63 Feb 25 18:07 autostart.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amir amir 259 Feb 25 18:07 touchpad_click.sh
```

---

Now the problem is that it doesn't work, and when I terminate dwm by `Shift+Alt+Q` shortcut, or when I reboot the system, the tapping of the touchpad is disabled. How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI, you don't need this `awk` mess in your script -- you can (and should) simply use the _names_ of the device and the property instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need to build dwm youself and write a special script which setup xinput properties. You can just use Xorg configuration file instead: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Via_Xorg_configuration_file

Create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf` that contains this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection
```

and restart Xorg.